# How to fix time lapse issues in Fallout Shelter

Tags: android, fallout-shelter

I've had Fallout shelter on my android phone from release on the 13th of Aug and all worked well. That was until I went to a mates wedding in Greece and changed the time on my phone to +3 and then back when I returned.

All the timers on the rooms, rush options and training times went screwy.

I have managed to reset the timers, the majority of which were fixed by rushing in each room or sending dwellers to train elsewhere or like the countdown for the radio room which went up to around 5 or 6 hours, they simply timed out and reset... But I have been left with a one remaining issue.

Now whenever I send a dweller out to explore nothing happens. They just head out into the wilderness and report nothing. I've sent every dweller in my vault out to explore for hours and hours and still they all report nothing.

Any ideas how I might resolve this issues? Clearing the Cache didn't help.